# Selecting controls from a dynamically generated Grid View

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Below is the code for a Grid View that I have. The Gird View is populated by a set of data returned from a database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True">
  <RowStyle BackColor="#000000" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#000000" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
  <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9933" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requestor">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Requestor" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("REQUESTED_BY") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Card Number">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="CardNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CARD_NUMBER") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Submitted">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="DateSubmitted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_SUBMITTED") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm?">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirm" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("EMAIL_SENT") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

When a box is ticked in the Grid View, users should then be able to press a button that calls the `ConfirmCards_Click` Sub.

```
Protected Sub ConfirmCards_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConfirmCards.Click

    Dim NumberOfRows = GridView1.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim ConfirmValue As CheckBox
    Dim CardNumber As Label

    Dim CardsConfirmed As String
    Dim RunNumber As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1

        ConfirmValue = GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("chkConfirm")
        CardNumber = GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("CardNumber")

        MsgBox(ConfirmValue.Checked & " " & CardNumber.Text, vbOKOnly, "Card and checked status")

    Next

End Sub
```

In the actual system, this sub would have funcitonality that marks a field in a database, confirming that the cards have been confirmed.

However, when clicking the button that calls the `ConfirmCards_Click` sub, the alertbox always comes back with False and the CardNumber of the rows, regradless of whether or not `chkConfirm` has been ticked.

How can I fix this? I have very similar code in another page that works just fine - is there some setting that needs to be applied to the page in order for the server to realise that the checkboxes have been ticked?

Edit: Including Page_Load VB code, as requested.

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim qryRaisedCards As String

    If TeamName.Text = "Admin" Then
        qryRaisedCards = "select CARD_NUMBER, REQUESTED_BY, DATE_SUBMITTED, EMAIL_SENT from SUBMISSIONS where EMAIL_SENT = 0 order by DATE_SUBMITTED, CARD_NUMBER"
    Else
        qryRaisedCards = "select CARD_NUMBER, REQUESTED_BY, DATE_SUBMITTED, EMAIL_SENT from SUBMISSIONS where EMAIL_SENT = 0 and TEAM_NAME = :TeamName order by DATE_SUBMITTED, CARD_NUMBER"
    End If

    Using cn2 As New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString), _
        cmd2 As New OracleCommand(qryRaisedCards, cn2)

        If TeamName.Text <> "Admin" Then
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(":TeamName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 60).Value = TeamName.Text
        End If

        Dim RaisedCardsAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd2)
        Dim RaisedCardsDataset As New DataSet()
        RaisedCardsAdapter.Fill(RaisedCardsDataset, "UserPermissions")

        cn2.Open()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn2.Close()

        If RaisedCardsDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ErrorMessage.Visible = False
            GridView1.DataSource = RaisedCardsDataset
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Else
            GridViewPanel.Visible = False
            ErrorMessage.Visible = True
            ErrorMessage.Text = "There are no submitted cards that have not been confirmed at this time."
        End If

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: How you are using MsgBox in asp.net? Also, are you getting only one alert? Also, have you done datagrid binding only in not IsPostback?

Comment: @Amit I'm getting as many alerts as there are records in the data grid. The MsgBox is in my VB.NET code. "Also, have you done datagrid binding only in not IsPostback?" - I don't understand this.

Comment: Kindly post Page_Load code.

Comment: @Amit All the Page_Load VB code does is add in the data to Grid View. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Can you wrap this in If Not IsPostBack Then and try.

Comment: @Amit Wrap which part - the ConfirmCards_Click sub or the Page_Load sub?

Comment: @Amit This now works perfectly (as far as I can see). If you would like to create an answer with the solution provided and an explanation of what went wrong and why this fixed it, I'll upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code what I see is your gridview is getting bound on postback also. Which causes loosing value of state with which it was posted back. try wraping your code of Page_Load in If not IsPostback then.

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim qryRaisedCards As String
If Not IsPostBack Then
    If TeamName.Text = "Admin" Then
        qryRaisedCards = "select CARD_NUMBER, REQUESTED_BY, DATE_SUBMITTED, EMAIL_SENT from SUBMISSIONS where EMAIL_SENT = 0 order by DATE_SUBMITTED, CARD_NUMBER"
    Else
        qryRaisedCards = "select CARD_NUMBER, REQUESTED_BY, DATE_SUBMITTED, EMAIL_SENT from SUBMISSIONS where EMAIL_SENT = 0 and TEAM_NAME = :TeamName order by DATE_SUBMITTED, CARD_NUMBER"
    End If

    Using cn2 As New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString), _
        cmd2 As New OracleCommand(qryRaisedCards, cn2)

        If TeamName.Text <> "Admin" Then
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(":TeamName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 60).Value = TeamName.Text
        End If

        Dim RaisedCardsAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd2)
        Dim RaisedCardsDataset As New DataSet()
        RaisedCardsAdapter.Fill(RaisedCardsDataset, "UserPermissions")

        cn2.Open()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn2.Close()

        If RaisedCardsDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ErrorMessage.Visible = False
            GridView1.DataSource = RaisedCardsDataset
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Else
            GridViewPanel.Visible = False
            ErrorMessage.Visible = True
            ErrorMessage.Text = "There are no submitted cards that have not been confirmed at this time."
        End If

    End Using
    End If
End Sub
```